# Windows Form Application in VC++ 2012‏

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I am wondering about the issue of removing “Windows Form Application” option in MS Visual Studio 2012. I saw the comment in [this page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747648/no-windows-forms-aplication-project-template-for-c-in-vs2012-rc-ultimate) saying:

> C++/CLI is a great solution for interop, but we do not recommend
>   creating brand new UI applications using C++/CLI.

Why don’t recommend creating brand new UI applications using C++/CLI? I used to create my UI application by C++/CLI.

Comment: I guess it is fine if you like the horrible syntax and verbosity of C++/CLI ;p

Comment: Because C++/CLI isn't going anywhere. I wish it was, but it's not. There are better languages for UI development. [Especially ones that allow you to debug them](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/751327/debugger-stepping-in-mixed-mode-application-is-very-very-slow).